# Calling Oracle functions from EJB in Seam framework

Tags: java, oracle, orm, jpa, seam

I am using seam framework and struggling to call a Oracle function. 
In my EJB, I am creating a namedQuery and when I call my `entityManager.getResult()` I get the following error:

> PLS-00222: no function with name 'jjhg' exists in the scope.

(jjhg is the name of my oracle function)

Comment: Please show the named query (not a native one?), please show the call, please confirm you can call the function from sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things which might cause this:

1. JIHG is a procedure rather than a function.
2. JIHG is a private function which has been declared out of scope of the current block.

As you're using a framework to call the program unit I suspect the first explanation is the more likely.